# HTTPS Connection Pool SSL certificate verification error

Tags: python, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I'm attempting to scrape a real estate listings website using Python 3 and the Requests library

```
url = 'https://www.mlslistings.com'
page = requests.get(url)
```

and I'm encountering the following error:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.mlslistings.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /Search/Result/299ae029-54cd-404d-bf6c-edab2dc896cc/1 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)')))
```

I'm able to solve the issue with

```
url = 'https://www.mlslistings.com'
page = requests.get(url,verify=False)
```

But I'm warned that

```
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
```

I followed the link and found their recommendation to `pip install certifi` and then try

```
import certifi
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())
http.request('GET', 'https://mlslistings.com')
```

But doing this gives me the same SSLError described above.

So I have two questions:
1. Why is adding certificate verification "strongly advised"?, and 
2. What can I do to get past this without simply giving up and using `verify=False`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to work without disabling verify go to the site with your web browser and export the root certificate (top item in the certification path) in base64 format.  Then when you make your call set verify equal to the path of the certificate you exported.

```
page=requests.get(url, verify='/path/to/exported/certificate.cer')
```

Why verify certificates?  To make sure you are doing things in a secure fashion.

Comment: How does one export the root certificate?

Comment: In chrome click on the lock icon.  Then click on Certificate.  Then click on Certification Path.  Click on topmost item and click on View Certificate. Click on Details, then click on Copy to File.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you missed `s` for ssl certificate in your url. Try with this

```
url = 'https://www.mlslistings.com'
page = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the error 
`SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.mlslistings.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)')))`
appears both with and without the `s` in the url.